# connection between hose web application and time attendance device

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, zkteco

i developed a desktop time attendance and payroll application on windows few years ago.
this application is connected to time attendance device and sends and receives some  data to device when needed for example get time that personnel s enter to office or leave office.
the connection of my application and time attendance device is over TCP/IP and both are within the same network.

but I am developing this application on web (new web application) and I don't know how I can establish an online connection between the device and the hosted web application online without a fixed IP for the device.

I am building my web application with .net core on the server side and Angular for the front.
please note that one of required features of this site is sending and receiving data with device online.

I thought the web socket might be my solution, but I welcome your suggestions

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Search for Asp.Neg Core API

Comment: Does the Web application still run in the office network? Or do you need to tunnel through the public internet?

Comment: In fact web application will host on public server and it is not on office network!

Comment: For enabling the communication between the zkteco biometric device and the web application, you need to use web API instead of the standard SDK. Refer to the API documentation: https://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html for more information